# Pagination with Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade

I'm trying to return data with a pagination. When I'm returning the data as paginate() I receive an error: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

My controller:

```
$tickets = Ticket::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->paginate(3);
```

Blade:

```
            <table class="bg-white overflow-hidden table-auto w-full flex-row flex-no-wrap whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th class="bg-white px-4 py-2">Updated at</th>
                <th class="bg-white px-4 py-2">Case Title</th>
                <th class="bg-white px-4 py-2">Manager</th>
                <th class="bg-white px-4 py-2">Case ID</th>
                <th class="bg-white px-4 py-2">Remaining</th>
                <th class="bg-white px-4 py-2">Status</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
            <tr class="bg-gray-100 text-center">
                <td class="px-2"><span class="text-blue-900 font-bold text-xs">
                        @if($ticket->isNew($ticket->created_at))
                        New
                        @endif
                    </span></td>
                <td class="px-4">{{ $ticket->updated_at }}</td>
                <td class="px-4 py-4">{{ $ticket->title }}</td>
                <td class="px-4 py-4">{{ $ticket->getAdmin->first_name }} {{ $ticket->getAdmin->last_name }}</td>
                <td class="px-4 py-4">{{ $ticket->id }}</td>
                <td class="px-4 py-4">
                    @php
                    $dueDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($ticket->end_date);
                    @endphp
                    @if($dueDate->isPast())
                    <span class="text-red-600">Overdue</span>
                    @else
                    {{ $ticket->remaining_date() }} Days
                    @endif
                </td>

                <td class="px-4 py-4">
                    @if($ticket->status == 1)
                    <span class="bg-yellow-500 font-semibold text-white p-2 rounded">Active</span>
                    @endif
                    @if($ticket->status == 2)
                    <span class="bg-blue-500 font-semibold text-white p-2 rounded">Closed</span>
                    @endif
                    @if($ticket->status == 3)
                    <span class="bg-red-800 font-semibold text-white p-2 rounded">Late</span>
                    @endif
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        
        {{!! $tickets->links() !!}}
```

I don't get it why I receive the error and have tried to Google around it. Why is the error appear and what's the solution?

Comment: its `{!!` not `{{!!` ... what line does it say is causing the error?

Comment: It should be `{{ $tickets->links() }}`, according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Comment: @aynber it can be either since `links` returns a view and View is Htmlable so it doesn't get escaped ... but i agree with `{{` as the safer choice

Comment: @lagbox Oops, just copied the wrong version, it's still the same error though. It's refering to helpers.php on line 118 (return htmlspecialchars($value ?? '', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode)

Comment: what line in your view is it referring to? ... there is a stack trace

Comment: @lagbox I use Tailwind as CSS framework and referring to this line: <nav role="navigation" aria-label="{{ __('Pagination') }}" class="flex items-center justify-between">

Comment: The CSS doesn't matter, this is a PHP error ... find out what `__('Pagination')` returns ... as it can return an array, which would be the problem ... and you should update your question with the code for what ever that line is coming from

Comment: That function is looking for any possible translations of `Pagination
`, so check any custom language files for that phrase.

Comment: @aynber Thanks! Helped once I deleted the Pagination.php inside lang/en/pagination.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your version of Laravel. This was a breaking bug for 8.78. They tried changing `Pagination Navigation` for screen readers, but it broke certain translation settings, so it was reverted back.  The details are at https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/39928

> @taylorotwell @xanderificnl This actually introduces a bug that breaks Tailwind pagination out of the box, and it should ideally be reverted.
>
> When attempting to use Tailwind pagination, I'm seeing the following: `htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given (View: /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/tailwind.blade.php)`
>
> The line causing the issue:
>
> ```
> <nav role="navigation" aria-label="{{ __('Pagination') }}" class="flex items-center justify-between">
> ```
>
> This is due to Laravel shipping with a `resources/lang/en/pagination.php` file by default. This PR causes the array returned by the pagination language file to be passed into the `__()` method, which results in the parsing exception.

Comment: Thanks, worked out for me!

Comment: nice catch there

Comment: @lagbox Thanks. Went down the rabbit hole when I noticed that his tailwind.blade.php didn't match mine

Comment: always nice when they introduce breaking changes `:)` ... fun timez